# Get document content results in "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'"

Tags: javascript, jsonp, alfresco, same-origin-policy, pdf.js

Hello i have a problem which isn't directly specific to Alfresco but it would be easier if someone already has some code of this.

I want to get the document from alfresco with the following url:
(host):(port)/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/8492e1bf-e144-4eb1-972f-9973e39b9af4/content.pdf

I'm using pdf.js to get the contents and show it in my page, but when the page loads it gives me the Same Origin Policy Error in the console because i am running my application on a local tomcat server and i am using Google Chrome. (IE doesn't have this issue i believe)

I googled the problem and it seems getting the data through JSONP is a workaround for this problem, but I couldn't find a way to work with JSONP with Alfresco, does anybody has any experience with this and so could you post some code for me to get how it works?

Here is my code by the way if it is needed:

```
var url = 'http://host:port/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/8492e1bf-e144-4eb1-972f-9973e39b9af4/content.pdf';


PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
  pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {

    var scale = 1;

    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is PDFJS coming from? Are you fetching the document content from *exactly* the same host/port/protocol/etc as where you're getting the JavaScript code from?

Comment: I included the pdf.js js library and the documentation said to use the PDFJS variable, but this code is almost a direct copy of the documentation and is working because otherwise it wouldn't throw this error. The document content is from Alfresco on another server so not the same host/port as the javascript code.

Comment: Where is it served from? And is that *exactly* the same host/port/protocol as where you're making the CMIS call to?

Comment: From github, no the application is on localhost:8080 and the server is on a different host and port

Comment: Can you get them onto the same box?

Comment: No, at least not for development but i know that fixes the SOP error but there are better options

Comment: Have your application server proxy through so everything appears to be on the same host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to override service servlet and add to header allow-origin .

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>apiServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.**WebScriptServlet**</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>authenticator</param-name>
         <param-value>webscripts.authenticator.basic</param-value>
      </init-param>
   </servlet>
```

In you class add

...
httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
...

Set for your domain.